# Azure Java Create Linux VM With Own VHD

Tags: java, linux, azure

I Have Gone Through all the resources Provided By Azure To Create Virtual Machine Using java. I was able to launch a new Linux Virtual Machine By Giving Specific Names to Resource Groups, Network Interfaces etc..

But i am unable to comprehend how to launch a Linux Virtual Machine with my Own vhd  Image....I have created a Linux Virtual Machine which has some required software installed.So now i want to use that Virtual Machine's vhd and Launch a NEW Virtual Machine Using Azure JAVA API...Can anyone help me?

Comment: This should be posted on ServerFault, not StackOverflow. That said: There are documented procedures for getting a VM configured for Azure. However, you'll likely find it far easier to re-create your VM image starting with one of the pre-made images available.

Comment: Yes i have started with pre-made image...but now i need my changes on that right....Can i have that documentation link...Specifically for Java

Answer (score 0):

As I know, first, you need to upload your own VHD into an exsiting Azure Blob storage. You can refer to the offical tutorial to do it, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-create-upload-vhd/#step-3-upload-the-image-to-azure.

Then, you can refer to the document of the REST API `Create or update a VM` for Azure Virtual Machine to know how to create a VM with a VHD, please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163591.aspx.

If you want to use Azure SDK for Java to do it, you can try to refer to the [javadocs](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/) for Azure SDK to use Java APIs instead of the REST APIs, please note the packages [`com.microsoft.azure.management.compute`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/package-frame.html) and [`com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.models`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/models/package-frame.html).

There is a video https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/creating-a-linux-vm-from-a-custom-image-with-azure-resource-manager-arm/, I think it's helpful for understanding.

Hope it helps.